# How to stop propagation on Link elements from React-Router-Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to fire stop propagation method on event object that is inside a `Link` component from React-Router-Dom. My problem is that when I click on the button that is inside the `Link` element it moves me anyway to another page. I see that the stopPropagation method is not working properly and the onClick event on the `Link` element is firing up. How to prevent this behavior?

I have prepared an example on codeSandbox but in this example, `Link` is not moving me to another page but only refreshing the page.

**Example**
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-surf-h65dz?file=/src/Home.js

My Code:

```js
const handleClick = e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  return console.log("Works?");
};

return (
  <Link to={`/edytuj/${item.ID}`} className="table__row">
    <Checkbox
      isSelected={isSelected}
      toggleSelection={() => handleSelection(item, isSelected)}
    ></Checkbox>
    <TableRowItem>{item.ID}</TableRowItem>
    <TableRowItem
      src={item.IMAGE}
      additionalClassName="table__image"
    ></TableRowItem>
    <TableRowItem>{item.NAME}</TableRowItem>
    <TableRowItem>{item.DESCRIPTION}</TableRowItem>
    <TableRowItem additionalClassName="table__cost">
      {item.COST} zł
    </TableRowItem>
    <TableRowItem additionalClassName="table__buttons">
      <Button className="btn btn__edit" icon="fas fa-pen btn__icon">
        Edytuj
      </Button>
      <Button
        onClick={e => handleClick(e)}
        className="btn btn__delete"
        icon="fas fa-times btn__icon"
      >
        Usuń
      </Button>
    </TableRowItem>
  </Link>
);
```

Button:

```js
const Button = ({ className, icon, children, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} className={className}>
      {children}
      {icon && <i className={icon}></i>}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: What is the purpose of a link if you don't want to nagivate? Can't you just use a regular old `div`?

Comment: Ok, I fixed that... e.preventDefault() must be called on children elements

Comment: I do want to navigate but on whole entire row, 2 buttons inside have their own actions. Clicking outside those buttons will move you to another page

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use e.preventDefault();

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return console.log("It works");
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/small-bird-65zgb?file=/src/Home.js

Comment: `The stopPropagation() method prevents propagation of the same event from being called.

Propagation means bubbling up to parent elements or capturing down to child elements.`

Whereas `The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.`

In this case, we have a 'native' html event (or at least its emulation in JS), therefore we want to cancle the default action.

Sources:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp